# How to close and restart bot conversation from UI

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I have created bot UI with this example https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat, but what I would like to do is create button with close chat window and restart conversation. Does anyone know how to implement this feature with bot framework v4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of steps you need to do to restart the conversation. First, you need to save your DirectLine and Store objects for the conversation in the parent component's state and pass them as props to the Web Chat component. Then you need to add a button to the screen with an `onClick` handler that dispatches an event to disconnect the DirectLine Object from the conversation. Then in the store's middleware you need to listen for the connection to be disconnected and reinitialize the DirectLine and Store Objects. This will clear the conversation history and start a new conversation. See the code snippet below for an example.

**Code Snippet**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine, createStore } from 'botframework-webchat';
import directLineDisconnect from 'botframework-webchat-core/lib/actions/disconnect';

const initializeDirectLine = async setDirectLine => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3978/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
  const { token } = await res.json();
  setDirectLine(createDirectLine({ token }));
};

const WebChat = props => {
  const { directLine } = props;

  return directLine
    ? <ReactWebChat className={'chat'} {...props} />
    : "Connecting..."
}

export default () => {
  const [directLine, setDirectLine] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeDirectLine(setDirectLine);
  }, []);

  const storeMiddleware = () => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/DISCONNECT_FULFILLED') {
      setDirectLine(null);
      setStore(createStore({}, storeMiddleware));
      initializeDirectLine(setDirectLine);
    }
    return next(action)
  };

  const [store, setStore] = useState(createStore({}, storeMiddleware));

  const disconnect = () => store.dispatch(directLineDisconnect());

  return (
    <div className={app}>
      <div className='details'>
        <button onClick={disconnect}>Disconnect</button>
      </div>
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <WebChat directLine={directLine} store={store}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

**Screen capture**

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: @tdurnford I like this snippet but am struggling with implementing it. I am using the minimizable webchat sample and would like a restart conversation button in the header. Do I need to implement this snippet as a seperate component or should I merge it in the  webchat or minimizable webchat component?

Comment: I would probably add the store middleware and the initialize Direct Line code to the minimizable Web Chat sample

Comment: @tdurnford I am using webchat cdn and normal js to create a webchat. Is there similar implemention of properly disconnecting a bot using js?