# How to reset/clear conversation in webchat react.js?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have a button in webchat, when i click in this button i need to reset conversation and start a new conversation. Can you help me about this with any code snipets.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you've tried, like the code attached to the button?

Comment: I had similiar problem and this post should help you :)
[Restart Conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857818/11728054)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the Web Chat store and create a new Direct Line connection to restart the conversation. There is currently a bug in v4.5 that won't allow you to do this; however, the issue has been resolved in v4.6 which should be released towards the end of the month. There is a pull request open in the Web Chat repo to add a [Clear Conversation After Idle](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/2375) Sample that will be merged when v4.6 is released.