# Reset conversation in webCaht UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-chat

I use WebChat as web interface for my bot and I would like to reset the conversation when the user click the reset button. I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56848336/how-to-close-and-restart-bot-conversation-from-ui) but the store dosen't reset the UI only the direct line is reconnecting.
 I have this error : uncaught at forkPut TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

- My code

> ```
> import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
> import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine, createStore } from 'botframework-webchat';
> import directLineDisconnect from 'botframework-webchat-core/lib/actions/disconnect';
> import './fabric-icons-inline.css';
> import './MinimizableWebChat.css';
>
>
> const initializeDirectLine = async setDirectLine => {
>   setDirectLine(createDirectLine({ token }));
> };
>
> const WebChat = props => {
>   const { directLine, store } = props;
>   console.log('DL : '); console.log(directLine);
>   return directLine
>     ? <ReactWebChat className={'react-web-chat'} {...props} />
>     : "Connecting..."
> };
>
> export default () => {
>   console.log('DL create req ');
>   const [directLine, setDirectLine] = useState();
>   useEffect(() => {
>     initializeDirectLine(setDirectLine);
>   }, []);
>
>   const storeMiddleware = () => next => action => {
>     console.log(action.type);
>     if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
>       store.dispatch({
>         type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
>         payload: {
>           name: 'webchat/NewConnect',
>           value: {
>             language: document.documentElement.lang || window.navigator.language
>           }
>         }
>       });
>     }
>     else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/DISCONNECT_FULFILLED') {
>       console.log("---> DIRECT_LINE/DISCONNECT_FULFILLED");
>       setDirectLine(null);
>       console.log("---> 1");
>       setStore(createStore({}, storeMiddleware));
>       console.log("---> 2");
>       initializeDirectLine(setDirectLine);
>       console.log("---> 3");
>     }
>     return next(action);
>   };
>
>   const [store, setStore] = useState(createStore({}, storeMiddleware));
>
>   const disconnect = () => store.dispatch(directLineDisconnect());
>
>   return (
>     <div className="minimizable-web-chat">
>       <div className='chat-box right bottom'>
>         <button onClick={disconnect}>Disconnect</button>
>         <WebChat className='react-web-chat'
>           directLine={directLine} store={store} />
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   )
> };
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Clear After Idle](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/17.b.clear-after-idle) Web Chat Sample. It shows how to clear the transcript history and create a new conversation with the bot. Note, you have to use the latest version of Web Chat - version 4.6.0 - for this sample to work. Older versions had a bug that wouldn't allow you to change the store without the 'forkPut' type error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with Web Chat version 4.6.0 there is a problem when minimizing the bot UI it reconnects automatically. Do you know if this issue will be solved in the next release ?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the issue you're seeing?

Comment: I  used the [minimizable  Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat) as a start point for my project.Whenn I update to Web Chat 4.6.0 to make the reset button, I noticed that every time I click on the minimize button to minimize the bot window the direct line reconnects to my bot. It starts a connection process after every click on the minimize button. Witch make my bot resend the welcome message every time I minimize and maximize my bot window.
[Video example](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AmEviMRo97nibQFCta-Ev6ZZPYU?e=2dlKhH)